# cordova navigator notfication alert does't work

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am having problem with cordova navigator alert. I called navigator alert method after `deviceReady` event is fired. I can't figure out why it is not firing.
Please check below my code and let me know how to solve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    window.onload = function(){                    
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);        
    }                

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listeners
        alert("Start !");
        navigator.notification.alert('Game Over!',gameOverDismissed,'Game Over','Done');
    }

    function gameOverDismissed(){

                }

</script>
```

config.xml

```
<name>hello</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
</feature>
<feature name="Vibration">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: Just to make sure, did you properly install the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin?

Comment: If it is still not working try the build command again as per your device

Comment: @E.Valencia thank you. I reinstalled plugin. after that it is working properly. I thought that dialogs plugin should be installed automatelly when I make cordova project.